# how to execute a batch file using a relative path added to the project

Tags: vb.net

i have created a batch file and have added it to the project using add items. Basically what i am aiming at is to execute this file on a button click action. 
I am using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("hello.bat") command to run this file
i have changed the build action to resource for this batch file.
But when i run this program, it is not able to locate the batch file. 
I am required to give a relative path as the path my vary from machine to machine. how can i make this file accessable using a relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource puts it inside of your EXE as data. You can google how to write a vb.net resource to a file, use the io tempfilename function to get a tempfile and use that (appending .bat), then run the batchfile from the name you gave it.

If you can ship the .bat with your EXE, this is convenient for debugging and production:
* Put the batchfile in the BIN subdir (debug or release) with your exe. May have to click 'show all files' in project explorer to see these dirs. Right click the .bat and pick 'include in project'. Don't make it a resource.

Run it using application.startuppath & "\" & batfilename. (application.startuppath is only in winforms. You can google 'how to get exe path in vb.net console app' etc. if you need another way).

Comment: Thanks for your help...application.startuppath gave the path of the location where the exes are stored after installation...and adding the batch file to the project resulted in the packaging of the file in the installer itself!